# What is essential to test after a power surge for an unprotected PC?

Tags: windows, windows-10, diagnostic, surge-protection

If a power surge occurs at such a level that a total blackout has occurred, but my Windows PC still boots correctly, what are the most vulnerable areas of my hardware that I should check or tests I should run if it was not surge protected?

Comment: perform a file system integrity check due to the bad shutdown, but other than that, theres nothing to test unless you start having trouble. Then about all you can test is that the disk is mechanically healthy, and that the RAM is still working properly. everything else is by guess. there is no diagnostic that will tell you whether you have blown capacitors, or other electrical damage on the mobo or CPU.

Comment: "Is it necessary to run tests at all if my PC boots correctly?" Any test(s) specifically?

Comment: @Moab Sorry it sounds a bit vague - is there anything I should be concerned for after a surge (except obvious massive failure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any *particular* tests you should do. After a power surge it's difficult to determine any specific part of the machine that would have failed. Ideally, you'd have a surge protector in place that would have stopped any damage to the machine. If not, then hopefully you'd have a power supply with functionality built in. And if that's not the case, then it's literally anyone's guess.

What *does* make sense is to make sure all of your backups are up to date in case something does fail, as if another part *has* failed it's usually not too difficult to replace. Your data however may be irreplaceable, and as such, that should be top of your concerns.

Comment: Thanks, I do have a board attached, but while I was browsing several posts recommended changing yearly, so I didn't mention it to avoid confusion - it's like 4 years old.

Comment: @Oman Changing once a year sounds a bit overly cautious really, unless you have frequent issues with power that give you the impression it may have failed. Ideally it would have an indicator light to tell you, but if not, it's hard to say. Backup and carry on, any issues would soon make themselves apparent if they exist :)